# Sql recursive error invalid column name CTE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, recursive-query

I have done following CTE it works fine,but I need to get sum of the last node so the problem is when I add T1.Debit Column to be calculated its give me an invalid column name 'Debit' !!! on line ***

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[SubTopics_GetSum]
 -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (
    @TopicID int
    )
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    WITH cte
    AS (
        SELECT
            T1.TopicID,
            T1.Code,
            T1.Description,
            T1.ParentID,
            T1.ParentID AS NewParentID,
            CAST(T1.Code AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS TopicCode,
            CAST(T1.Description AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS TopicDescription,
            isnull((Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0) AS Debit,
            isnull((Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0) AS Credit
        FROM Accounting.Topics AS T1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounting.DocumentDetail
                ON T1.TopicID = Accounting.DocumentDetail.TopicFK
        where NOT EXISTS(
                        SELECT
                            T2.TopicID,
                            T2.Code,
                            T2.Description,
                            T2.ParentID,
                            isnull((Accounting.DocumentDetail.Debit),0) AS Debit,
                            isnull((Accounting.DocumentDetail.Credit),0) AS Credit
                        FROM Accounting.Topics AS T2
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounting.DocumentDetail
                                ON T2.TopicID = Accounting.DocumentDetail.TopicFK
                        WHERE (ParentID = T1.TopicID)
                        )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            c.TopicID,
            c.Code,
            c.Description,
            c.ParentID,
            T1.ParentID AS NewParentID,
            CAST(T1.Code AS nvarchar(MAX)) + c.TopicCode AS TopicCode,
            CAST(T1.Description AS nvarchar(MAX)) + ' - ' + c.TopicDescription AS TopicDescription,
            ***   isnull((T1.Debit),0)+isnull(c.Debit,0) AS Debit,--IN THIS LINE error 'Invalid Column Name 'Debit''
            isnull(c.Credit,0) AS Credit
        FROM cte AS c
            INNER JOIN Accounting.Topics AS T1
                ON T1.TopicID = c.NewParentID
        )

    SELECT isnull(sum(Debit),0)AS Debit,
        isnull(sum(Credit),0)AS Credit
    FROM cte AS c
    WHERE (NewParentID = @TopicID)
)
```

let me know whats wrong with my code confused !!!

actually it doesn't return me a last node sum of debit,credit ... !!!
check following pic

[image]

Comment: For help us to find the line you can well format the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below code will help,

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Subtopics_getsum] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
(@TopicID INT) 
returns TABLE 
AS 
    RETURN ( 
      -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here 
      WITH cte 
           AS (SELECT T1.topicid, 
                      T1.code, 
                      T1.description, 
                      T1.parentid, 
                      T1.parentid                                     AS 
                      NewParentID 
                      , 
                      Cast(T1.code AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
                      AS TopicCode, 
                      Cast(T1.description AS NVARCHAR(max))           AS 
                      TopicDescription, 
                      Isnull(( accounting.documentdetail.debit ), 0)  AS Debit, 
                      Isnull(( accounting.documentdetail.credit ), 0) AS Credit 
               FROM   accounting.topics AS T1 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN accounting.documentdetail 
                                   ON T1.topicid = 
                                      accounting.documentdetail.topicfk 
               WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT T2.topicid, 
                                        T2.code, 
                                        T2.description, 
                                        T2.parentid, 
    Isnull(( accounting.documentdetail.debit ), 0) 
    AS 
    Debit, 
    Isnull(( accounting.documentdetail.credit ), 0) AS 
    Credit 
    FROM   accounting.topics AS T2 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN accounting.documentdetail 
    ON T2.topicid = 
    accounting.documentdetail.topicfk 
    WHERE  ( parentid = T1.topicid ))) 
    SELECT Isnull(Sum(debit), 0) AS Debit, 
    Isnull(Sum(credit), 0)AS Credit 
    FROM   cte AS c 
    WHERE  ( newparentid = @TopicID )
    )
```

Comment: still do not return the last node sum !!

Comment: Can you explain desired output with example?

Comment: I have one table which have parent child rows in it (stores accounting topics) and its related to other table "documentdetail" that store the accounting rows NOW 
I need to calculate each topic balance(debit,credit ...)  like the attached picture in first post but if you look at picture I can't get the sum of the debit ,credit for that selected node which is the last one ,as you can see my code return 0 for last node but on that selected row it must return credit=5000000,debit=0

Comment: I cannot understand attachment numbers. English please.

Comment: sorry , its english now check it out plz

Comment: By selected node, do you mean node that is highlighted in pic (Mr.xyz)?

Comment: What value does your cte query brings for description Mr.xyz? (if your cte query is throwing error then tell results of my posted query) I think inner cte query is not bringing any record for topic id 28.

Comment: @Patrik Kage which query did you posted ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37900/discussion-between-franchesco-totti-and-pratik-kaje)

Answer (score 0):

I think you `Accounting.Topics` hasn't column `Debit`.

**UPDTAE**

isnull((**T1.Debit**),0)+isnull(c.Debit,0) AS Debit,--IN THIS LINE error 'Invalid Column Name 'Debit''
                isnull(c.Credit,0) AS Credit
            FROM cte AS c
                INNER JOIN **Accounting.Topics AS T1**
                    ON T1.TopicID = c.NewParentID

In the code above your `T1.Debit` refers to `Accounting.Topics`.

Comment: Accounting.Topics doesn't have but here I call T1.Debit which this column is defined for it in top lines!

Comment: so how can refer to the 'accounting.documentdetail.debit' instead of 't1.debit' ?

Comment: but it doesn't return me last node sum !!